# Dependency conversion: difference between version of Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have used stanford-corenlp-full-2015-01-29 to convert basic dependencies generated by the MALT parser to CCprocessed dependencies. 
In my experiments, I want to compare MALT and Stanford Parser, so I am parsing the same texts with s stanford-corenlp-full-2015-04-20, using the neural network model. 
My question is: are there significant differences between 2015-04-20 and 2015-01-29, as far as not Universal Dependencies are concerned? In that case, not to affect my comparison, I'd need to either parse with the older version, or redo the conversion with the newer one.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think there were no SD differences between 2015-01-29 and 2015-04-20, but it would be easy to run both conversions and to diff the output.... Did you train your own MALT parser? I think the one distributed on the MALT site was done with an earlier version of our dependencies.

Comment: I used the latest available MALT model, and I adapted the basic dependencies produced by MALT relying on the "Recent changes" section of the manual.